# Multiple Insert Queries using promise-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, electron

```
   <script>
    $("#addopdfrm").submit(function(){
    var opdname = $("#opdname").val();
    var opdsex = $("#opdsex").val();
    var opdage = $("#opdage").val();
    var opdaddress = $("#opdaddress").val();
    var opdcity = $("#opdcity").val();
    var opdstate = $("#opdstate").val();
    var opdpin = $("#opdpin").val();
    var opdcon = $("#opdcon").val();
    var opdmail = $("#opdmail").val();
    var opdpresfee = $("#opdpresfee").val();
    var odate = new Date();
    var opdmonth = odate.getMonth()+1;
    var opdyear = odate.getFullYear();
    var opdday = odate.getDate();
    var opddate = opdday+"/"+opdmonth+"/"+opdyear;
    var opdtime = Date.now();
    var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
    var connection;

    mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'plasmadoc'
    }).then(function(conn){
        connection = conn;
        return connection.query("INSERT INTO `opdrec` VALUES('', '"+opdname+"', '"+opdage+"', '"+opdsex+"', '"+opdcon+"', '"+opdaddress+"', '"+opdpin+"', '"+opdcity+"', '"+opdstate+"', '"+opdmail+"', '"+opddate+"', 'no', '"+opdtime+"')");
    }).then(function(rows){
        var result = connection.query("INSERT INTO `opdvisits` VALUES('"+rows.insertId+"', '"+opddate+"', 'Prescription Fee', '"+opdpresfee+"', 'Waiting', 'no', '"+opdtime+"')");
    connection.end();
    return result;
}).then(function(rows){
    // Logs out a ring that Frodo owns
    alert("New  Record Added");
});     
    });

    </script>
```

I want to execute the first query. Retrieve the id of inserted row which is auto increment primary key and then use that id to insert data in different table.
Only the first query is executing. The second query is not executing. please help

Comment: *Only the first query is executing. The first query is not executing.* Does it execute or not? You contradict yourself.

Comment: try transction querys

Comment: iam batman can u please eleaboraye a bit. i read the documentatiin but cant get much. how do i fetch the results of first query and execute 2nd query in transaction

Comment: chade_2 sorry... the second query is not executing

Comment: i am batman tried transactions also.. still the same problem